# Java - splitting files by newline

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, split

How can I split file by newline? I've attempted to split by doing `line.split("\\r?\\n")` - but when I try printing the 0th index I get the entire file content when I was expecting just the first line. but if I try printing the result at index 0 I get the entire file content, when I expected to get just the first line.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("file.rcp");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
String line = reader.readLine();

 while (line != null) {
            String [] split = line.split("\\r?\\n");
            String name = split[0]; // test to see if name will print the first line only
            System.out.println(name);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
```

File format

```
Food name - gyros
author - some name
Cusine type - greek
Directions - some directions
Ingredients - some ingredients
```

Comment: @Abra I've added a sample rcp file, its just another file extension type sort of like a txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`readline()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--), says:

> Returns a String containing the contents of the line, **not including any line-termination characters**

Which means that `line.split("\\r?\\n")` is the same as `new String[] { line }`, i.e. it's an entirely useless thing to do.

If you want to read the entire file into memory as an array of lines, just call [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-):

```java
List<String> linesList = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.rcp"));
String[] linesArray = linesList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: I've already read in the file, so I dont see the point of `Files.readAllLines()`. also I don't want to read my file into an array of lines, I want to read in my file then split each line until seperate variables

Comment: @sjw037 `readLine()` only reads one line at a time, which means that the input is already "split" into lines, without any need to call `split()`. --- And no, you haven't already read in the file, the code in the question is doing the reading of the file, and this answer is showing you how to do that with 1 line of code, instead of the 9 lines in the question code, which is wrongly written too, since it doesn't correctly close the file after reading it. --- Or are you opposed to learning better ways of doing things?

Comment: ah I see I didn't realize that `readLine()` already "splits" the line, also I did close the file It just wasn't included in the example. But I will test it  when I get back to my PC @Andreas.

Comment: @sjw037 You did close the file? But did you do it *correctly*? Using try-with-resources, or at least with `try-finally`?

Comment: yep I closed it with a `try-catch-finally` block

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to split any string at all. You can simply read a line and add it to a `List<String>` (or an array if the number of lines is known).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("file.rcp");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file))) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                list.add(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(list);

        // An array out of the list
        String[] arr = list.toArray(new String[0]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Food name - gyros, author - some name, Cusine type - greek, Directions - some directions, Ingredients - some ingredients]
[Food name - gyros, author - some name, Cusine type - greek, Directions - some directions, Ingredients - some ingredients]
```

If you have already read the content of your file into some string (e.g. `String fileContent` as shown below), you can simply split the string on `\r?\n` which will produce a `String[]`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.rcp")));
        // Java11 onwards
        // String fileContent = Files.readString(Path.of("file.rcp"));

        String[] arr = fileContent.split("\\r?\\n");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Food name - gyros, author - some name, Cusine type - greek, Directions - some directions, Ingredients - some ingredients]
```

Comment: Not releasing resources. Very bad example. Please, lets not teach bad coding practices here. --- Besides, why do all that, when the first 8 lines of code can be done with a simple call to `Files.readAllLines()`?

Comment: You are mistaken, [`Files.readAllLines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) is there in Java 7.

Comment: *FYI:* `split("\\r?\\n")` is better written as `split("\\R")`, where regex pattern [``\R``](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) means *"Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`"*